# svn on mac os X, SSL error: point is not on curve

Tags: macos, svn, ssl, macports

I have a problem with svn on my mac. When I trying to commit changes or checkout sources of my project from code.google.com, I got the following error:

Ibis:grid-gen$ svn -m "" commit
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://grid-gen.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://grid-gen.googlecode.com/svn/trunk': SSL handshake failed: SSL error: point is not on curve (https://grid-gen.googlecode.com)

How to fix this?

MacOS 10.8.2, iMac (64 bit), svn version 1.7.7 (r1393599) compiled Nov 18 2012, 00:18:52
Subversion was installed from macports, now I cannot use system svn (1.6.18), because working copy is in 1.7 format.

On my other mac svn works fine with same repository (10.8.2, MBP 64 bit, svn version 1.6.18 (r1303927) compiled Aug  4 2012, 19:46:53)

Comment: You need to tune-up SSL in order not to use elliptic-curve cipher suites. Unfortunately I have no idea how to set this on rotten fruits.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with macports/openssl (thanks to Eugenes followup!), the way to fix it described here: http://trac.macports.org/ticket/38015